# Remote branches from Gerrit to Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, gerrit

Recently we have moved from using gerrit to Bitbucket. There are few remote branches in Gerrit which need to sycned to Bitbucket. Since the number of branches is high, an automation is needed. Any pointers will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample jenkinsfile to push remote branches from gerrit to Bitbucket -**

```
// ssh credentials
def credentials_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-UUUUUU-III'

pipeline {
  options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '600'))
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
  }

  agent { node { label 'Master' } }

  stages {
    stage('try') {
      steps {
        checkout(
          [
            $class: 'GitSCM',
            branches: [
              [
                name: '${gerrit-branch-name}'
              ]
            ],
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
            extensions: [
              [
                $class: 'CheckoutOption',
                timeout: 20
              ],
              [ $class: 'LocalBranch',
                localBranch: '${local-branch-name-bitbucket}'
              ]
            ],
            gitTool: 'Default',
            submoduleCfg: [],
            userRemoteConfigs: [
              [
                credentialsId: credentials_id,
                name: 'gerrit',
                url: '${gerrit-URL}'
              ],
              [
                credentialsId: credentials_id,
                name: 'bitbucket',
                url: '${bitbucket-URL}'
              ]
            ]
          ]
        )
      }
    }
    stage('Push updates of branch to Bitbucket') {
      steps {
          bat 'git push --tags bitbucket ${gerrit-branch-name}:refs/heads/${local-branch-name-bitbucket}`enter code here`'
      }
    }    
  }
}
```